# rfid tags: same tag, different codes on different readers

Tags: rfid

Is anyone familiar with RFID codes here?

I have a EM4102 type tag here. My handheld reader says on it's display:

```
EM4102 tag, ID 04178649C1
```

The same tag, when read on a Gigatek/Promag PCR125 CF-card reader gives me the exact same code:

```
04178649C1
```

However, an ACG RF PC CF-card reader gives me the code

```
20E8619283
```

This reader is capable of reading different types of tags and also reports the correct type (EM4x02, length 5 bytes).

I have tried a few readers of the same model and they all give me the same code.

I guess that reader just reports the code in a different way. Perhaps I have to shift some bits around (wouldn't be the first time) or there are error correction bits still included in the code?

FYI, the reader is documented [here](http://www.cardnology.com/files/20090221164810_lf_multitag_v1_0_user_manual_02.pdf). The section regarding this type of tags just states:

> The EM4x02 label only provides a 5 bytes serial number. The label
>   starts to send its response immediately after entering an energizing
>   field. Each transponder has its own unique serial number, which cannot
>   be changed.

Any clue what the reader is doing?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out myself.

20E8619283 in binary is:

```
0010 0000   1110 1000   0110 0001   1001 0010   1000 0011
```

These are five bytes, two nibbles each. Mirroring the bit order of each byte (bit 0 becomes bit 7, bit 1 becomes 2 etc.) I get:

```
0000 0100   0001 0111   1000 0110   0100 1001   1100 0001
```

which in hexadecimal notation is 04178649C1, the correct code.

So apparently the reader is not interpreting/reporting the bits in the right order...